# Function to exclude Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a "Daily Sales Query" that captures all the Total Sales entered from the previous work day which runs Mon-Fri at 8AM.

Question is, if it is Monday today, how can I capture the records from Friday.
so that I can exclude  weekends.

Because if it is Monday, the total sales displays 0 which actually makes sense because Sunday is a not a work day. Please assist.

See my current code:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 103) AS Date, 
    'Sales Orders' AS Type, 
    COUNT(o.SalesOrderID) AS Orders, 
    SUM(d.QtyOrdered) AS Chairs, 
    ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(d.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST] 
FROM 
    dbo.SalesOrder o
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.SalesOrderDetails d ON o.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID 
WHERE 
    (o.EntryDate >= CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 112)) 
    AND (o.EntryDate < CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)) 
    AND (o.CustomerID <> 187);
```

Comment: *Please* learn to format your SQL in a readable format.

Comment: Also, when declaring/converting with `(n)(var)char` always make sure you declare your length. Note, as well, that "Three-part and four-part column references." are deprecated. When you reference a column you only need to provide the table name/alias and column name. You should not include the schema and database name.

Comment: Why are you converting your dates to chars to compare them?

Comment: They aren't @DaleBurrell just `GETDATE()`. I *think* they're effective doing `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())`, as style 112 is the ISO format (`yyyyMMdd`). It is rather odd way of doing it though and implies the OP is using `datetime` to store data that always has the time value `00:00:00.000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a case statement to determine how many days in the past you need to go e.g.

```
dateadd(dd, case when datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 1 then -3 else -1 end, getdate()) -- StartDate
dateadd(dd, case when datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 1 then -2 else 0 end, getdate()) -- EndDate
```

so your code would look like

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateadd(dd, case when datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 1 then -3 else -1 end, getdate()), 103) AS Date, 
    'Sales Orders' AS Type, 
    COUNT(o.SalesOrderID) AS Orders, 
    SUM(d.QtyOrdered) AS Chairs, 
    ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(d.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST] 
FROM 
    dbo.SalesOrder o
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.SalesOrderDetails d ON o.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID 
WHERE 
    (o.EntryDate >= CONVERT(CHAR(8), dateadd(dd, case when datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 1 then -3 else -1 end, getdate()), 112)) 
    AND (o.EntryDate < CONVERT(CHAR(8), dateadd(dd, case when datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 1 then -2 else 0 end, getdate()), 112)) 
    AND (o.CustomerID <> 187);
```

PS: Do confirm that weekday `1` is Monday on your server.

Comment: Yes, Monday is the weekday 1. Shall I put this code on my WHERE clause? @dale burrell

Comment: @TrishFernandez See edits - still not sure why you are converting the date to a char(8)?

Comment: thank you :) This works! Sorry for a dumb question, may I ask why you had use o.EntryDate? What I meant is why you had used "o."

Comment: @TrishFernandez your original code had `o.`? That's called a table alias and is a good practise for writing clear concise queries as it allows you to reference the table name in a much shorter form. Its necessary if you ever join a table on itself (self-join).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datediff(dd,0,getdate()) % 7 = 0` to determine if the current date is a Monday regardless of any other server settings (this is because the zero date in SQL Server is 1900-01-01 which happens to be a Monday).

```
declare @start date;
declare @finish date;

set @start = dateadd(dd, case when datediff(dd,0,getdate()) % 7 = 0 then -3 else -1 end, getdate());
set @finish = dateadd(dd,1,@start);

select
    @start, datename(weekday,@start)
  , @finish, datename(weekday,@finish)
  , datename(weekday,getdate())
;
```

So in your query I would use:

```
declare @start date;
declare @finish date;

set @start = dateadd(dd, case when datediff(dd,0,getdate()) % 7 = 0 then -3 else -1 end, getdate());
set @finish = dateadd(dd,1,@start);

SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, @start, 103) AS Date, 
    'Sales Orders' AS Type, 
    COUNT(o.SalesOrderID) AS Orders, 
    SUM(d.QtyOrdered) AS Chairs, 
    ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(d.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST] 
FROM 
    dbo.SalesOrder o
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.SalesOrderDetails d ON o.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID 
WHERE 
     o.EntryDate >= @start
    AND o.EntryDate < @finish
    AND o.CustomerID <> 187
;
```